# Better method for updating data table

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-datatable

I have completed an application which gathers specific records and marks them as `Collected`. As of now, the application runs perfectly and does exactly what I need it to, but the problem comes in when a large data set is reviewed. If I am pulling records for one day or even maybe a week, it runs at a decent pace, but once you get a month of data or more, it takes a fairly long amount of time.

```
DataTable ModelData = getModelData() // Returns all records to search.
...
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> modelRows = (from model in ModelData.AsEnumerable()
                                              where (model.Field<object>(GeographicalKey) ?? (object)String.Empty).ToString() == GeographicCode
                                              select model);
ModelResults = modelRows.Any() ? modelRows.CopyToDataTable() : ModelData.Clone();

for (int i = 0; i < ModelResults.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ModelData.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (ModelResults.Rows[i]["Request ID"].ToString() == ModelData.Rows[j]["Request ID"].ToString())
        {
            ModelData.Rows[j]["Collected"] = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

The only part that executes slowly would be the `for` and the nested `for`. Is there possibly a better way that I can code this? I can't imagine this is the optimal coding for data table update operations, but it might be.  Is this a possibility in LINQ (I'm completely new to LINQ)? I think this is enough code to make sense of what I'm doing, but if more is needed just let me know and I can post it up as well.

Answer (score 4):

> The only part that executes slowly would be the for and the nested
>   for. Is there possibly a better way that I can code this?

I take you ask us to optimize the nested loops:

The most obvious problem, as @Antonio also noted, is the O(n^2) filtering in the nested `for`s. Also as he noted, you need some kind of data structure with O(1) `Contains` method. However since you do not use other fields of from the rows of `ModelResults`, you only need a `HashSet` of `["Request ID"]`s.

> I can't imagine this is the optimal coding for data table update
>   operations, maybe though? Is this a possibility in LINQ (I'm
>   completely new to LINQ)?

I take you are asking for a more compact, more LINQy way of updating a collection, in this case a `DataTable`:

LINQ is a query language and a LINQ query does not modify underlying `IEnumerable`. (In most cases you would `select` a modified copy of the underlying `IEnumerable`, instead.)

However, you can use `List.ForEach` on the result of such a query, as a more compact replacement of `for` loop.

Applying two suggestions above, we get:

```
var collectedRequestIds = new HashSet<string>(
    modelResults.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["Request ID"].ToString()));

modelData.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(collectedRequestIds.Contains(row => row["Request ID"].ToString())))
    .ToList().ForEach(row => row["Collected"] = "1");
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few optimizations that can be done in your code (such as using a `break` in the inner loop after a match is found - but reverting the order of the 2 loops) - but leaving the complexity order to O(n^2).

A better approach instead is using a dictionary. Since you have a list of results, identified by a unique ID (`Request ID`), and a list of rows, uniquely identified in the same way, I would:

- create a dictionary, adding all `ModelData` rows, using `Unique ID` as key
- remove the 2nd loop, and just check for an element in the dictionary having the same ID as the `ModelData` row - if a match is found, set the `Collected` flag

This should reduce the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).